# spark reads the file on the client instead of on the worker

Tags: apache-spark

mymaster:

```
$ ./sbin/start-master.sh
```

myworker:

```
$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://mymaster:7077
```

myclient:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://mymaster:7077
```

at this moment, the log of myworker says the following, indicating that it has accepted the job:

```
16/06/01 02:22:41 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160601022241-0007/0 for Spark shell
```

myclient:

```
scala> sc.textFile("mylocalfile.txt").map(_.length}).sum
res0: Double = 3264.0
```

It works if the file mylocalfile.txt is available in myclient. However, according to the [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html), the file should be available in myworker, not in myclient.

> If using a path on the local filesystem, the file must also be
>   accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to
>   all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system.

what am I missing here?

---

Comment: Doc says "must ALSO be" .  That means in addition to the client, worker nodes need it to be accessible in order to read it.

Comment: so, how does it work? if i have one driver, one master, and ten workers, who will read the file? one of them randomly? will one of them read all the file, split it and send it to the others? or will all of them directly read part of the file?

Comment: The workers will get the file name and the offset from which it has to read the file (combinedly known as split). The workers get the information on which split to read and they read just the part that is required. That's why its required on all worker nodes. Master needs it too to create split info.

Comment: i see. so, the file will be read by the master and by the workers, but never by the client/driver. is this correct? but this contradicts my case, because the file was read by the client/driver (because it was the only one who had access to the file). how is that possible?

Comment: do you have a link where it explains that "The workers will get the file name and the offset from which it has to read the file"?

Comment: I have no link for this info, but you can very well get it from the debug logs if you switch them on